# Sigma algebra generated by a quadratic function

Tags: measure-theory

I have a little difficulty determining what $\sigma(F)$ looks like for $$F: [0,1] \ni x \mapsto 1- |2x^2-1| \in [0,1]$$

I know that $F(x)=F(y) \iff x = \sqrt{1-y^2}, \ \ x,y \in [0,1]$.

$\sigma(F) = \sigma( \{F^{-1}(B) : B\in \mathcal{B}_{[0,1]} \})$ where $\mathcal{B}_{[0,1]} $ are borel sets on $[0,1]$ is not enough.

I need a more direct representation of $\sigma(F)$ as a family of sets satisfying certain conditions, because I will need to integrate over them later.

The problem is that the graph is not symmetric, the peak is at $x =\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ and to every value, except for $y=1$ we have two arguments, as mentioned above.

Could you help me find out what $\sigma(F)$ is in this case?

Comment: I vaguely recall it is sufficient to represent all open intervals.

Comment: @gt6989b I think it is sufficient, but what would those open intervals be?

Comment: If $f$ is *any* measurable function then it's sigma algebra is generated by half-open intervals $(a,b]$.

Comment: @AlexR. Thank you. Could you tell me what conditions should those intervals satisfy?

Comment: @Sasha: it's the entire collection of these intervals. I think you are confusing the domain and range. The sigma algebra contains all sets which are preimages of open sets.

Comment: @AlexR. But will $(0,1/2)$ be the preimage of any open set?

Answer (score 1):

$\sigma(F)=\{\sqrt{X/2} \cup \sqrt{2-X/2}: X \in \cal{B}([0,1])\}$.

Comment: Wait, how exactly do we take a square root of a set?

Comment: $\sqrt{X/2}=\{ \sqrt{x/2}:x \in X\}$.

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay. So if we want to characterize the sets is $\sigma(F)$ by writing $X \in \sigma(F) \iff X \in \mathcal{B}[0,1] $ and $\forall x \in X ...$ we can write  that $\forall x \in X : \sqrt{x/2} \in X$ or $\sqrt{2-x/2} \in X$. So the generator of the sigma algebra will be an interval of this form: $[a,b] \cup [\sqrt{1-b^2}, \sqrt{1-a^2}]$?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I need a generator of this sigma algebra in order to integrate over it. So I take an interval $[a,b], 0 \le a \le b \le 1$. Then I take $[c,d], 0 \le c \le d \le 1/2$, then $[\sqrt{c}, \sqrt{d}]$, and $[\sqrt{2-c}, \sqrt{2-d}]$. But the problem is that $c$ could be $=0$ and then $\sqrt{2-c} >1$. Or maybe you meant $\sqrt{(X-2)/2}$. Then everything is fine :)